# Ubuntu 404 not found on sub directory

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I have site working on var/www/html folder.

I have another site on var/www/html/mynewsite.

And when i try to access it like this server ip 1.2.3.4/mynewsite

Its not working getting 404 not found error.

Apache Configurations

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/public/"  Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews AllowOverride All #Order allow,deny Require all granted

Comment: What web server are you using (apache/nginx/other) ? Can we see the config ? Did you try restarting your webserver ?

Comment: using apache. i have not tried restarting

Comment: DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/public/"
<Directory "/var/www/html/public">
 Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
 AllowOverride All
 #Order allow,deny 
 Require all granted
</Directory>
config file for main site. @LolWalid

Comment: `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public/` look like you have to put your `mynewsite` under `/var/www/html/public/` and not `/var/www/html/`, don't forget to reload your apache config

Comment: Could you edit your post and add your apache configuration so other users can easily see your problems

Comment: that site already have public folder.... the public folder is entry point of our main website as well as sub directory

Comment: Ok I got it now, Look at my answer let me know if that helps

Answer (score 1):

According to apache official [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts/examples.html), the easiest solution is to use `serverName` configuration field.

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/html/public"
    ServerName www.mainsite.com

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/html/mynewsite"
    ServerName www.mynewsite.com

</VirtualHost>
```

For testing you can change your local `hosts` to make `www.mynewsite.com` and `www.mainsite.com` redirect to `1.2.3.4`)

When going live you'll have to change your dns.

Hope that helps

Comment: the thing here is i have IP only not any domain name. i appreciate your help but not sure about ServerName here.

Comment: So you are trying to access to 2 distinct webapplication using only one IP and without domain name? Not sure it is possible. And serverName can be an IP

Comment: yes that's what i want to achieve. i mean if we can access root with ip how come we cannot access subdirectory with /